# group by select max in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to find out how to do this but still confuse with Linq sytax.

My purpose is to find the max effectiveDate with the specify empCode

```
var x = (from workingResult in this.DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.WorkingResults
         group workingResult by workingResult.EmployeeCode into g
         where g.EmployeeCode == employeeCode
         && (g.EffectiveDate.HasValue
         && g.EffectiveDate.Value.Equals(date))
         select new {EffectiveDate = g.Max(d=>d.EffectiveDate)});
```

but the compiler shows me this

" Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type'...'. 'GroupBy' not found. Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'workingResult'. "

What is this means ? I really really need your help. 
Thank you.

Comment: What type is `this.DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.WorkingResults`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are treating the group `g` as if it is a single workingResult. In reality it is a list of them. Furthermore, what is the purpose of `g.EffectiveDate.Value.Equals(date)`? It would result in the maximum effective date always being `date` or nothing, if no effective date exists that matches the `date` variable.

The following should work:

```
DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.WorkingResults
             .Where(x => x.EmployeeCode == employeeCode)
             .Max(x => x.EffectiveDate);
```

This will return the maximum `EffectiveDate` for the specified `employeeCode`.

Answer (score 1):

The line `where g.EmployeeCode == employeeCode` is invalid. The `g` is of type `IEnumerable<IGrouping<_EmployeeCode type_, _Working result type_>>`. Try the following:

```
var x = from g2 in (from workingResult in this.DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.WorkingResults
                    group workingResult by workingResult.EmployeeCode into g
                    select g)
        select new {EmployeeCode = g2.Select(w => w.EmployeeCode), MaxEffectiveDate = g2.Max(w => w.EffectiveDate)};
```

Now `x` contains `IEnumerable<_EmployeeCode type_, _Effective data type_>` of max `EffectiveDate` for each `EmployeeCode`.